# ! I can't write on file `"p-kahler hyperbolic.pdf"'. Please type another file name for output ! Emergency stop

Tags: pdftex

When I compile my tex document I get following message:

> ​ ! I can't write on file test.pdf. Please type another file name for output

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks   = true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4.2cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3.4cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2cm}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have your PDF file opened in some PDF reader, for example Adobe Reader? Then please close the PDF file in your reader and try to typeset the document again.

Comment: No, and when I compile any tex documents I get the same problem!

Comment: @Marouani are you sure you have writing permissions for the folder your documents are in?

Comment: i dont interstand

Comment: how can i verify this

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I use  Windows 7

Comment: Did you delete "test.pdf" first? Maybe your useraccount has no permission to overwrite it.

Comment: how can i check this i dont understand much about this 
and i don't know if i deleted "test.pdf"

Comment: Did you already save your document in your LaTeX editor? If yes, do you get an error when you do that? If not, then maybe that is the problem, because the compiler does not know where to put the pdf and it may try to store it in a system folder where it is not allowed.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the compiler does not know where to put the pdf and it may try to store it in a system folder where it is not allowed as you said. how can i solve it,?

Comment: Which editor do you use, and what is your pdf viewer?

Comment: Normally when you save your `.tex` file in a folder, then the pdf file will be created in the same folder. If you have write permissions to save the `.tex` file then you also have write permissions to save the `pdf` file. So, did you save the `.tex` file from the editor? Was that succesful, or did you get an error there as well?

Comment: Note that it is possible that the editor specifies a different output folder for the pdf file somewhere in the build options, but that is not very likely. Still, it would be useful to know which editor you use, and to check how it is configured.